# What is difference between host checks and service checks in Nagios and why both are needed?

Tags: nagios

Nagios has two kinds of objects:

- hosts, which represent systems with distinct IP addresses
- services, which are associated with hosts

Each host is considered a collection of services; for example, we can monitor SSH service, CPU usage, disk space available on some computer, in which case this computer is considered a "host" and the three items are all considered "services".

What I don't understand is why Nagios has distinct [host checks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/hostchecks.html) and [service checks](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/4/en/servicechecks.html). Reading those two pages already shows that those concepts are pretty similar, the logic behind is almost identical. Why both of them exist at all? It was possible to consider a host as a pure collection of services which run together, and define its network reachability and other status properties as properties of some service, and perform a "service checks" of that service. So "host checks" seem to be redundant. And, indeed, Zabbix (which is other network monitoring solution) has no concept of "host checks".

Or are there some subtle yet important differencies, which I don't still get?

Answer (score 2):

Like most other things, when trying to understand Nagios you need to remember that the initial release was in 2002, but its predecessor (NetSaint) was released in 1999. It's over 20 years old, and it shows in how the basic architecture of the software was designed.

What you call a "design deficiency" is nothing more than a lack of understanding on your part of how environments looked back then. A sysadmin around the turn of the century most likely had a bunch of physical servers they had to monitor, and each of those physical servers ran one or more applications. For many servers, or other devices such as routers, a ping was more than enough.

Based on this, the hierarchy of "host checks" (almost always ping) and "service checks" belonging to a host makes sense, because environments were very static. Of course, if you apply the thinking of today, which this is an excellent example of:

> consider a host as a pure collection of services which run together

...then of course, some of the design decisions do not make sense: but nobody thought like this in 1999, and why would they? Containers and virtualization either for any practical purposes did not exist, or they were an academic exercise or contained to hobbyist environments, so why would anyone consider a host as something so abstract as "simply" a collection of services; it was, quite the contrary, a very physical thing that you could touch, and you were maybe even involved in installing that physical thing in a rack. It was something that you, a lot of the time, had an actual relationship with. In the real world, sysadmins wrestled physical servers which normally each had a very specific purpose. It was the world of "pets, not cattle".

The entire tone of the question warrants some measure of humility, and perhaps you should for the sake of argument ask the opposite question instead: why has Nagios, despite of these obviously antiquated design decisions, survived for two decades and continues to be widely used to monitor infrastructure to this day?

The answer is that even if some of the objects that exist in Nagios haven't kept up with the times, it's simple, reliable, and does its job very well if you configure it correctly. It is designed on top of exit codes, something fundamental about UNIX systems that hasn't changed in 20 years and is unlikely to change in the coming 20 years: if you can check what you want to check in a script, you can have Nagios run that check. It's modular, it's simple (but not easy) and it's battle-tested.

And to answer the question in your headline, there is no difference. Objects in Nagios, like in any programming language for example, are made up. They exist simply to make configuration easier and more obvious. Hosts and services are abstractions, just like contacts and commands.

At the end of the day, Nagios is `cron` with bells and whistles, and those bells and whistles solve real world problems: but critiquing the design decisions of software from 1999 with a 2022 perspective is a bit like asking why a perfectly maintained Volvo 960 from 1998, despite being a luxury model, does not support Apple Carplay.

Comment: Oddly enough, I knew how environments looked like that days. Software evolves, design changes are made to be more adequate to the environments it is going to be used. Like, Linux dropped support for i386, for which it was released initially. I am not critiquing the Nagios from 1999, but I am critiquing Nagios v4, generally released in 2013, and latest version in 2022. And, the question I asking would be adequate even in 1999, because it was never a good idea to copy-paste code. GoF released their book in 1994 and already critiqued this approach, and it predates Nagios.

Comment: It has nothing to do with containers. And I thought maybe I don't get it, maybe, there is some subltle important thing that is different — they keep both things from release to release for 20 years already after all. And I admit, everybody is allowed to make mistakes, nobody is required to foresee a future, but making the same mistake for 20 years is way too much, and could not be regarded as "unforeseen consequence" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you get the difference but you are looking for reasons:

Imagine a host crashing and not being reachable anymore. Without this setup your host triggers any check on him.. Might be 20 or even more checks you have to go through before you realize what is happening.

With this setup it just shows your host as down and you know right away where you're at.

There are also organizational reasons for when you have to setup multiple hosts with the same checks. Easy copy paste and any service check works automatically.

I guess this approach is a little bit more old school and hierarchical compared to newer solutions.

Comment: There are also service dependencies in Nagios and what you are talking about is pretty easily resolved using these. In particular, don't even check/report problems with "application" services which depend on "reachability" service if it happens to be "down". So we'd go to check "reachability" first which is reported as parent/more important.

Comment: right, that's what I meant with hierachical. I don't know if this feature is standard nagios but we use even a higher "layer" where we bound multiple hosts and services together which belong to the same service we provide. So if any part of this process fails we see immediately which of our services is disrupted.

Comment: So you didn't answered why separate "host checks" are needed (and configured). It has own commands for passive checks, own schedule/notification/etc. configuration, and other things that essentially duplicate generic service check logic, and I don't understand the purpose of this duplication.

Comment: if you duplicate those checks or not is on you. what is sure is that service checks don't need to be done if the host is down (determined by host checks, often just ping).
Schedule and notification might differ on importance of the check, example: You want to know if the host is running, but don't care if memory is on 100%

Comment: I am concerned not with duplicating checks themselves, but with duplicating concepts and objects in the Nagios. I am trying to find a reasoning behind this duplication, or to ascertain it is a design deficiency in Nagios, at least.

Comment: we for example only use a simple ping for the host check. everything else is handled by service checks. This makes sense in our environment where a lot of hosts are remote with sometimes rather unstable connections. So if nagios cant ping the hosts it won't use resources and traffic to try and do complex service checks. Maybe this might also be a concept for you.
Those hosts are also linked to the associated network devices which helps to minimize alerting to the "true" source.
Which host checks make sense in your environment do you have to determine.